# Multiple errors while building WebAssembly project

Tags: blazor-webassembly, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to build simple webassembly app that consumes a JS object reference (of type `emscripten::val` or `emscripten::EM_VAL`).

The code:

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <emscripten/val.h>

extern "C"
{
    EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void Draw(emscripten::val canvas)
    {
        emscripten::val::global("console").call<void>("log", canvas);
    }
}
```

I have tried to build the project that consists only of the code above using `emcc` (installed according to [instruction](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emsdk.html#how-do-i-just-get-the-latest-sdk)), Emscripten CMake toolchain and Blazor WebAssembly (C#/.NET, [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-native-dependencies?view=aspnetcore-8.0)). Regardless of the way the C++ code is being attempted to compile to wasm, I see the same multiple errors in the output:

```
NativeClient_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_get_global
NativeClient_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_decref
NativeClient_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_call_void_method
NativeClient_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_get_method_caller
NativeClient_0.o: undefined symbol: _emval_incref
```

There are some related issues on github ([1](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/13017), [2](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/2372)). Apart from that I was unable to find any related info and couldn't get my code compiled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Windows 10 and msvc and also that errors are happening during linking stage, since the errors are emitted from wasm-ld.exe.

Comment: These are all `embind` symbols, are you sure you are linking with `embind`? When using `em++` from the CLI, `embind` is an option (`--bind`). Don't have an idea about Blazor, check its documentation.

Comment: @Criminal_Affair_At_SO many thanks, I must have missed something in official docs about `embind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--bind` for emcc and em++ compilers and remove `-s WASM=1` if using it.

Comment: Thanks, as you and Criminal_Affair_At_SO suggested, using `--bind` got my compilation going. Too bad I missed that in docs.